# Execute a cgi script from a Node Express server

Tags: node.js, express, npm, cgi

So I have a website with a member area. That member area is managed through a payment processor called CCBill. In order for CCBill to manage a password file on my server, they need to execute a cgi script.

Right now, I've looked at cgi and serve-cgi npm modules. But I'm not sure if they can do what I need. Can anyone help me with this?

My Express Router get function:

```
router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('in');
    var mPath = path.join(appRoot, '/cgi-bin' + req.params[0]);
    console.log(mPath);
    const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
    const child = execFile(mPath, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw error;
        }
        console.log(stdout);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts (and other executables) can be invoked with the [exec()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exec) function:

```
var exec = require('exec');
exec('/path/to/your/script',
  function (stderr, stdout, errorCode) {
    // You get here when the executable completes
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

With newer node.js versions `exec()` is deprecated, so it's better to use [child_process.execFile()](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#child_process_child_process_execfile_file_args_options_callback):

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('/path/to/your/script', [parameters], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  // You get here when the executable completes
});
```

Comment: I use
`var mPath = path.join(appRoot, '/cgi-bin' + req.params[0]);`

  `console.log(mPath);`

 `execFileSync(mPath);`

I get an error saying invalid data

Comment: How are your variables `path`, `req` and `execFileSync` defined and which values do they have? It would help if you would post a minimal, but complete code example.

Comment: Console.log(mPath) prints: `d:\Davelopment\WEBSITE_NAME\cgi-bin\dmBCX63nfJKb2EvSFQ7tgkeL5cowVsaD\wm_668.cgi`

Comment: Ok, I see, with Windows, it is a little more complicated. Try calling 'cmd.exe' with '/c' and your cgi path as first parameters instead. See https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows for some background.

Comment: That gave me the prompt asking which program I want to open cgi files with. My windows machine is my localhost. Once live it will be Ubuntu

Comment: `execFile` needs an executable, and your cgi-scripts doesn't seem to be executable directly. The documentation should contain information about how these scripts can be executed. Depending on their programming language this may require some interpreter.